# Error integrating piggybak with rails admin. Undefined method 'nestable'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, piggybak

I try to integrate piggybak in my rails application, using the example initializer for rails_admin from

https://github.com/piggybak/demo/blob/master/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

When I try to start up the server I get the following error:

/home/dumand/Desktop/Projects/3dgreen/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method`nestable' for RailsAdmin::Config::Actions:Module (NoMethodError)

This is the server log:

```
/home/dumand/Desktop/Projects/3dgreen/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `nestable' for RailsAdmin::Config::Actions:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config.rb:239:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config.rb:239:in `actions'
    from /home/dumand/Desktop/Projects/3dgreen/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:21:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin.rb:29:in `call'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin.rb:29:in `config'
    from /home/dumand/Desktop/Projects/3dgreen/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/dumand/Desktop/Projects/3dgreen/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/dumand/Desktop/Projects/3dgreen/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/dumand/Desktop/Projects/3dgreen/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/dumand/Desktop/Projects/3dgreen/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /home/dumand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

and here is rails_admin initializer:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  config.main_app_name = ["3D Green"]

  ### Popular gems integration

  ## == Devise ==
  # config.authenticate_with do
  #   warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  # end
  # config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  ## == Cancan ==
  # config.authorize_with :cancan

  ## == PaperTrail ==
  # config.audit_with :paper_trail, 'User', 'PaperTrail::Version' # PaperTrail >= 3.0.0

  ### More at https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Base-configuration

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app

   nestable do
    visible do
      [::PiggybakTaxonomy::NavigationNode].include? bindings[:abstract_model].model
    end
   end

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    # history_index
    # history_show

    config.model Product do
      edit do
      include_all_fields
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with removing nestable taxanomy code because it seems that you didn't uses nested taxanomy as per your models also